# Pass data between childViewControllers Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I put a `container` inside my `MainViewController`. Then added `FirstViewController` inside that `container`

```
let containerView = UIView()
view.addSubview(containerView)

let controller = FirstViewController()
addChildViewController(controller)
containerView.addSubview(controller.view)

controller.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

There are a `UITextField` and a `UIButton` inside `FirstViewController`. There is a label inside `SecondViewController` and `var passedText = ""` to update the UILabel text. I just want to set the UILabel text according to the `UITextField` text from `FirstViewController` when I press UIButton and it should leads to `SecondViewController` as well. This is the UIButton action method from `FirstViewController`. I'm not using `Storyboard`

```
@IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
   let secondVC = SecondViewController()
   addChildViewController(secondVC)
   view.addSubview(secondVC.view)

   secondVC.view.frame = view.bounds
   secondVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

   secondVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
   secondVC.passedText = inputTextField.text!
}
```

This is `FirstViewController`

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

  @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

  let secondVC = SecondViewController()

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  }

  @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    addChildViewController(secondVC)
    view.addSubview(secondVC.view)

    secondVC.view.frame = view.bounds
    secondVC.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

    secondVC.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
    secondVC.passedText = inputTextField.text!
  }        
}
```

This is `SecondViewController`

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

  var passedText = ""

  @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    label.text = passedText
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use protocols and delegates or closures

Comment: Can you please specifically brief as answer?

Comment: As I understand you have a parent controller in which you add the first controller. And in the first controller you add a second controller. And you need to transfer data from the first to the second controller?

Comment: Yes. I know I can pass data with `pushviewcontroller`. But the issue now is I need to add `FirstViewController` inside the `container` which is from `MainViewController`. Then I need to remove `FirstViewController` as child view and add `SecondViewController` inside that `container`. Plus need to pass data from previous child viewcontroller to next child view controller.

Comment: A few minutes. I'll try to explain

Comment: You can keep the data at the level of the parent controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Closure

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController {

    var embeddedViewController: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstViewController = FirstViewController()
        embedViewController(firstViewController)
        firstViewController.passDataClosure = { [weak self] text in
            let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
            self?.embedViewController(secondViewController)
            secondViewController.passedText = text
        }
    }

    func embedViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        removeEmbedded()
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        embeddedViewController = viewController
    }

    func removeEmbedded() {
        embeddedViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        embeddedViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        embeddedViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    }
}
```

-

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    var passDataClosure: ((String?) -> Void)?

    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        passDataClosure?(inputTextField.text)
    }
}
```

-

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var passedText: String? {
        didSet {
            label.text = passedText
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

> Delegate

```
class ParentViewController: UIViewController, FirstViewControllerDelegate {

    var embeddedViewController: UIViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let firstViewController = FirstViewController()
        embedViewController(firstViewController)
        firstViewController.delegate = self
    }

    func embedViewController(_ viewController: UIViewController) {
        removeEmbedded()
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
        addChildViewController(viewController)
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
        embeddedViewController = viewController
    }

    func removeEmbedded() {
        embeddedViewController?.view.removeFromSuperview()
        embeddedViewController?.didMove(toParentViewController: nil)
        embeddedViewController?.removeFromParentViewController()
    }

    // MARK: FirstViewControllerDelegate
    func firstViewController(_ firstViewController: FirstViewController, pass text: String?) {
        let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
        embedViewController(secondViewController)
        secondViewController.passedText = text
    }
}
```

-

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

    var passedText: String? {
        didSet {
            label.text = passedText
        }
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
}
```

-

```
protocol FirstViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func firstViewController(_ firstViewController: FirstViewController, pass text: String?)
}

class FirstViewController: UIViewController {

    weak var delegate: FirstViewControllerDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var inputTextField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func btnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.firstViewController(self, pass: inputTextField.text)
    }
}
```

Comment: You can also use delegates instead of closures

Comment: I tried delegate but couldn't managed to do. Maybe I did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, this should work:

```
secondVC.label.text = inputTextField.text
```

You currently have `secondVC.label = inputTextField.text` which shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Sorry. I was wrongly explained. `label` is not the name of the label inside `SecondViewController`. I updated my question.

Answer (score -1):

you can create a singleton class for your scenario. so that you can access all of your important data from anywhere either from your firstViewController or SecondViewController.

```
class YourDataClass : NSObject{

var textFieldData = String()
var lblSeconddata = String()
 struct Static
    {
        public static var instance: YourDataClass?
    }

    class var singleton: YourDataClass
    {
        if Static.instance == nil
        {
            Static.instance = YourDataClass()
        }

        return Static.instance!
    }
}
```

now somewhere in your controller

```
YourDataClass.Singleton.textFieldData = txtFld.Text
YourDataClass.Singleton. lblSeconddata = lblText.Text
```

in smame way you can get it anywhere

Comment: I should create a new Swift file?

Comment: no you can just write it in any of your controller file as you write extension

Comment: I just put your class inside `FirstViewController` and put `YourDataClass.singleton.textFieldData = testTxt.text!` inside button action method. Then I tried to set label as `label.text = YourDataClass.singleton.textFieldData` inside `viewDidLoad` of the `SecondViewController`. Still the label is empty.

Comment: can you share your code. so that i can see clearly where your making mistake

Comment: don't put that singleton class inside your class, that ill be writen somewhere out of every class(where your FirstViewController class ends).

Comment: I put singleton class outside of `FirstViewController` class.

Comment: okay so now on button click get your textField data and set in singleton class variable and then set your lbl as. lbl.text = YourDataClass.singleton.textFieldData